# How to write tables data to a flat file in Cognos?

Tags: cognos

In Cognos, I would like to write 100 tables output to 100 flat files. I am planning to create a Project, which will be scheduled everyday. When it runs, it will write tables output to flat files.

Can you please tell me whether this is possible or not. If so, can you please specify the approach to solve this problem?

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a report for each table. I presume you know how to do it.
2. On a Cognos Connection portal create a job with all your reports and set up out put for all your reports.
3. Schedule execution of your new job.

1 task described in Report Studio User guide (And Framework Manager Developer Guide if you don't have model for your table)
2-3 in Cognos connection User Guide. Check out "Use Jobs to Schedule Multiple Entries"

Comment: Thank you. It helped me. One question remains is, i want to download the report output file from an automated program(I am ready for any language). Is it possible to download that file automatically? I can see the option to download report output file manually.

Comment: You can set up saving you file to a folder. Here is good guide for it http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21342666